# Tail subprocess in socketio in flask application

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using the following example utilizing socketio library in flask:

> https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/tree/master/example

I'd like to execute a command via `subprocess()`, and emit its output to `socketio` in the background thread.

I am using ping as the example here. The following does not seem to work:

```
def background_thread:
   command = ['ping', '-n', '3', '127.0.0.1']                                                            
    process = Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE,                                        
                    close_fds=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid)                                                 

    session['pid'] = process.pid                                                                          

    for out in iter(process.stdout.readline, b""):                                                        
        out = '<pre>' + out + '</pre>'                                                                    
        count += 1                                                                                        
        socketio.emit('my response', {'data': out, 'count':count}, namespace='/test')                     
        time.sleep(0.001)                                                                                 

    socketio.out = "Command finished." + '<br /><br />'                                                   
    emit('exec_terminate', {'data': out})
```

As a matter of fact if I try to use the `socketio.emit()` function out of the while loop as shown in the example.

It does not seem to work, which has me quite confused.

Comment: I assume you monkey patched the standard library?